# How do I output a variable in a rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a quick way to output the value of variable in a rspec test? Something like this for example, in a controller to output a variable, I do:

```
raise variable.to_yaml
```

Is there something similar I can do in a rspec test to see the contents of a variable?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you want the output to go into the log file (i.e. logs/test.log), you can use the rails logger.

```
Rails.logger.debug variable.inspect
Rails.logger.debug variable.to_yaml
```

If you want to see the output in the console, you can use the pretty printer 'pp'.

```
require 'pp'

it 'does something'
  thing = Factory(:something)
  pp thing
end
```

Or you can use good 'ol puts

```
puts thing.to_yaml
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks ipd. 'pp' was exactly what I was looking for. (It worked for me without the "require 'pp'" statement too.)

Comment: Yea, sometimes 'pp' has already been required somewhere in your Rails stack.

Comment: None of these work for me :( Or rather, none of the `pp` options, nor the `to_yaml` options.

Answer (score 6):

At this moment (Rails 4) you can log it:

`p variable`

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$stderr.puts variable.to_yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem pry to do this

1. add gem "pry" in your gemfile
2. `bundle install`

Now you can any test any variable by putting "binding.pry" just after that variable. Run `bundle exec rspec filepath` and you will get something like rails c, then write directly your variable.

I hope it makes sense