# How can I better debug in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to testing, and having troubles debugging like I might normally in a model or controller.

I've created a user from a factory (using FactoryGirl, if that makes a difference), and I'm pretty sure the create method is failing because of validation when saving. However, I'd love to know how to debug a model instantiated during testing.

I've tried:

```
user.inspect
puts user
raise user.to_yaml
```

(The latter works, but stops execution of the rest of my tests, and doesn't show validation errors--it only proves the existence or non-existence of the model I tried to instantiate.)

Other than raising the model as an error, there is no debug output during testing, and the only other thing I've been able to do is tail the log for my test DB and see what's happening there, but it seems clunky at best. What methods would you suggest for accomplishing what I'm after?

Thank you for any direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer, it couldn't be easier (this user phrased my question much better and more concisely :)

[How do I output a variable in a rspec test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025803/how-do-i-output-a-variable-in-a-rspec-test)

short answer, use pretty print:

pp user

Answer (score 2):

Checkout plymouth: https://github.com/banister/plymouth

It works with PRY to give you a nice REPL & debugging interface when a test fails. I've used it on some projects and found it very very handy for obscure issues in tests.

Comment: thanks @agmcleod. Plymouth looks good for at least showing more details about errors, but i don't see a way to debug model instantiation in there.

Comment: I love the concept of Plymouth!  Before I try it out, does anyone know of a version that's maintained?  EDIT: "Use pry-rescue, it's the spiritual successor to plymouth:"

Answer (score 0):

You can always crack open a `pry` session by adding `binding.pry` to your test. That way you can have access to whatever is available at the exact point in the test (and elsewhere if desired). More info on adding `pry` to Rails in the [official Pry wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry)